# Updating sideloaded add-in with Excel for iPad

Tags: excel, ipad, office-js, office-addins

Does anyone have experience updating existing Task Pane add-in, and know the correct procedure to replace / update existing add-in, to ensure latest version is loaded when re-inserted into a  workbook?

I am currently in process of developing and testing aTask Pane add-in for Excel for iPad. I am able to successfully sideload the initial .xml manifest file through iTunes and add the app to a workbook via the Insert->Add-in menu. When I make changes to add-in backend HTML/ JS code however, and attempt to update to later version by deleting and re-sideloading the manifest file via iTunes, more often than not, the previous version Task Pane add-in keeps getting displayed.

Occasionally the update works and reloads correctly when inserted into a workbook, however mostly, it doesn't and the previous version HTML is retained and displayed in the Task Pane.

I have tried deleting previous manifest file via iTunes, closing add-in from workbook, closing and restarting Excel before re-sideloading, inserting add-in to new workbook, even clearing cache in Safari browser via iOS settings, and rebooting iPad, however cannot determine any consistent or reproducible procedure.

It appears that the add-in is being cached by Excel, however, cannot find any direct way to clear the cache to force the workbook to reload the updated HTML file referenced in the .xml manifest file.

Appreciate any guidance on cause and correct procedure to update existing add-in with Excel for iPad.

Comment: Does the section of this article on clearing the cache provide any help? https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac#clearing-the-office-applications-cache-on-a-mac-or-ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of making sure that you have the latest version is versioning. If you have something like

```
<script src="xyz.com/abc.js">
```

Every time you load the app, even if the js is new, it might pick up from the cache. Instead try doing something like

```
<script src="xyz.com/abc.js?v=1.2">
```

Which now is seen as a different reference. Ideally automate the versioning on your js / css so you bypass the sticky cache when you update your add-in

Comment: Thanks, implementing versioning the source html file in manifest resolved the issue. As suggested, simply changed:

Comment: Simply changed the source reference with version parameter to force reload.

e.g.

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://server.com/Home.html" />`

changed to:

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://server.com/Home.html?v1.2" />`